# Opening a new window with defined HTML

Tags: javascript

At http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/, if you right-click on one of the equations and do Show Math As > TeX Commands, a new window opens (url is the same as `http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/`) containing some LaTex code.

I want to do the same thing: define some HTML and open a new window containing it.

I looked in the source for MathJax and found this file: http://code.google.com/p/jaxedit/source/browse/trunk/jaxedit/mathjax/config/TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML.js?r=79. I believe the relevant functions are `a.ShowSource`, `a.ShowSource.Window`, and `a.ShowSource.Text`, but how do I adapt them to do what I want?

Here are the functions in prettified form: http://pastebin.com/c4UKgSgT

Comment: `a.ShowSource.Text()` seems pretty straightforward. It opens a window, calls `s.document.open()`, calls `s.document.write()` to put HTML into the window, then calls `s.document.close()`.

Comment: Given that, you should be able to write what you want. If you run into trouble, post what you've tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! I figured it out from your annotations!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use window.open() method to create the new window. Then, you can manipulate the HTML of the new window through its document property.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp.) is an example.